rails-erb-loader error and MiniRacer::RuntimeError in Rails HomeController#index
I’m encountering an error when trying to run my Rails application on AWS EC2 instance (AWS EC2 supporting Linux). The error occurs in the HomeController#index and seems to be related to the rails-erb-loader module. Here are the details:
ExecJS::ProgramError in HomeController#index
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js):
Rails.root: /home/ec2-user/siam-mha

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
(execjs):279:18
(execjs):282:10
app/controllers/concerns/set_locale.rb:36:in `switch_locale'
Exception Causes
MiniRacer::RuntimeError: Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js):


What I’ve tried:

I’ve checked the set_locale.rb file for any issues but couldn’t find anything that stands out.

I’ve also looked into the rails-erb-loader documentation for potential configuration issues.


My environment:

Rails version: 6.0.3.5

Ruby version: 2.7.2

Node.js version: 14.16.0


Question: Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide insight into what might be causing these errors? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Note: We able to run the application successfully on the local machine but the error occur on dev env
What I’ve tried:

I’ve checked the set_locale.rb file for any issues but couldn’t find anything that stands out.

I’ve also looked into the rails-erb-loader documentation for potential configuration issues.



Would bet you don't have node installed properly on the instance

You don't actually need/want MiniRacer. MiniRacer is used to embed the v8 JS engine in Ruby instead of using an actual runtime such as Node.js which is a very outdated approach. Remove it from your Gemfile.

Also check if you actually need rails-erb-loader. You can pass configuration data to your scripts via DefinePlugin.
